# AngularUI Bootstrap modal close event for any instace

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using UI Bootstrap AngularUI and I need to call a function when any modal is closed.
I know that I can call a function when a specific modal instance closes like this:

```
modalInstance.result.finally(function(){
    console.log('Modal closed');
});
```

In jQuery I would do something like this for ANY instance:

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    console.log('Modal closed');
});
```

But how to achieve that with AngularJS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
myApp.controller('ModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', function($scope, $modal) {
    $scope.open = function() {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'modal.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            resolve: {
                params: function() {
                    return {
                        key: 'value',
                        key2: 'value2'
                    };
                }
            }
        });
        modalInstance.result.then(
            function(result) {
                console.log('called $modalInstance.close()');
                alert(result);
            },
            function(result) {
                console.log('called $modalInstance.dismiss()');
                alert(result);
            }
        );
    };
}])
```

And something you could from your `controller`.

```
myApp.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'params', function ($scope, $modalInstance, params) {
    console.log(params);

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close('this is result for close');
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('this is result for dismiss');
    };
}]);
```

Found a neat fiddle over this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/wjohtz0y/

Comment: Hi Thalaivar, can you answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583136/bootstrap-modal-popup-open-and-close-using-angularjs-not-working